# How to fix "Uncaught TypeError: action.addEventListener is not a function" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to work on a Tic Tac Toe game using JavaScript. During my process, I got stuck in the `addEventListener` part. I am getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: action.addEventListener is not a function

error. How can I fix this issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="game.css">

</head>
<body>

    <h1>Ultimate Tic Tac Toe</h1>
    <h2>Turn: </h2>
    <h3><span class="P1">Player 1</span> <span class="P2">Player 2</span></h3>
    <div id="grid">
        <a href="img/black pic.jpg"></a>
        <div class="S1"><img src="img/black pic.jpg"></div>
        <div class="S2"><img src="img/black pic.jpg"></div>
        <div class="S3"><img src="img/black pic.jpg"></div>
        <div class="S4"><img src="img/black pic.jpg"></div>
        <div class="S5"><img src="img/black pic.jpg"></div>
        <div class="S6"><img src="img/black pic.jpg"></div>
        <div class="S7"><img src="img/black pic.jpg"></div>
        <div class="S8"><img src="img/black pic.jpg"></div>
        <div class="S8"><img src="img/black pic.jpg"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="game.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
body{
    background: url("img/wooden.jpg");
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#grid{
    font-size: 0;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#grid div{
    margin: 2px;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
}

#grid div:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```
const action = document.querySelectorAll("#grid");

action.forEach(action.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.log(e);
}));
```

Comment: You're trying to add an event listener to your collection stored in `action`, you need to add it to every element within `action`: `action.forEach(act => act.addEventListener(...));`

Comment: Refer to the [docs for `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (here, technically the [`NodeList.prototype` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)). `action.addEventListener("click", …)` isn’t a function, even if `action` was an `EventTarget`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be passing a function to the `forEach` method:

Using arrow functions:

```
action.forEach(action => action.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.log(e);
}));
```

Comment: I think this works. I am no longer getting the error. Thank you!